# XSD schema: restriction on attribute inherited by another element

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a problem with my XSD schema.
I have an element called  which have an attribute id of type xsd:string and it must have no restrictions.
Then there's another element  which extends  and has several more attributes BUT the inherited attribute "id" has to be composed by letters and digits only. Here is my code:

I've tried to add both  and  to  and give id attribute a new type but it doesn't work.

```
<xsd:complexType name="BaseElement">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" />
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Element">
    <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:restriction base="BaseElement">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:idNewType" />
    </xsd:restriction>
    <xsd:extension base="identifiedEntityType">
           <xsd:attribute name="attr2" type="xsd:string"/>
           <xsd:attribute name="attr3" type="xsd:string"/>
          </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define a restriction and an extension in a single step, but you can define X as an restriction of Y, and Y as an extension of Z, so the extension step would add two attributes and the restriction step would then restrict one of them.